# spring mvc quartz: how to set the scheduler from the view or a html page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

hi i'm working with spring mvc and quartz so far i have done a simple example of printing a message in the console every certain time, but now i want to set that time from a html page, i mean give the user the ability to put a number in a textbox like this: `seconds: 4` and the message would be printed every 4 seconds, how can i do this?? the example that i did you put the time in config xml file.

this is what i have so far:

this is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">




    <!--QUARTZ PRUEBA  -->

            <beans:bean id="runMeTask" class="com.abc.domain.RunMeTask" />

            <!-- Spring Quartz -->
            <beans:bean name="runMeJob" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">

                <beans:property name="jobClass" value="com.abc.domain.RunMeJob" />

                <beans:property name="jobDataAsMap">
                  <beans:map>
                    <beans:entry key="runMeTask" value-ref="runMeTask" />
                  </beans:map>
                </beans:property>

            </beans:bean>

            <!-- 
            <bean id="runMeJob" 
                    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean"> 
                <property name="targetObject" ref="runMeTask" /> 
                <property name="targetMethod" value="printMe" /> 
            </bean> 
            -->

            <!-- Simple Trigger, run every 5 seconds -->
            <!-- <beans:bean id="simpleTrigger" 
                        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean">

                <beans:property name="jobDetail" ref="runMeJob" />
                <beans:property name="repeatInterval" value="5000" />
                <beans:property name="startDelay" value="1000" />

            </beans:bean> -->

            <!-- Cron Trigger, run every 5 seconds -->
            <beans:bean id="cronTrigger" 
                        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">

                <beans:property name="jobDetail" ref="runMeJob" />
                <beans:property name="cronExpression" value="0/2 * * * * ?" />

            </beans:bean>

            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
                <beans:property name="jobDetails">
                    <beans:list>
                        <beans:ref bean="runMeJob" />
                    </beans:list>
                </beans:property>

                <beans:property name="triggers">
                    <beans:list>
                        <beans:ref bean="cronTrigger" />
                    </beans:list>
                </beans:property>
            </beans:bean>

    <!--FIN QUARTZ PRUEBA  -->


</beans:beans>
```

and this are my classes:

```
public class RunMeTask {

    public void printMe() {
        System.out.println("Spring 3 + Quartz 1.8.6 ~");
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class RunMeJob extends QuartzJobBean {

    private RunMeTask runMeTask;

    public void setRunMeTask(RunMeTask runMeTask) {
        this.runMeTask = runMeTask;
    }

    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context)
        throws JobExecutionException {

        runMeTask.printMe();

    }

}
```

Comment: hi paul can you pls put back your answer i wdidnt save yout link

Answer (score 1):

You can inject scheduler in your mvc controller:

```
@Autowired
private Scheduler scheduler;
```

and add the following method that you can call with the new cron expression to reschedule it:

```
public void rescheduleTrigger(String cronExpression) throws ParseException,
        SchedulerException {

    CronTriggerImpl cronTrigger = (CronTriggerImpl) scheduler
            .getTrigger(new TriggerKey("simple"));

    cronTrigger.setCronExpression(cronExpression);
    scheduler.rescheduleJob(cronTrigger.getKey(), cronTrigger);

}
```

For a better design approach you could put the above code in a separate class e.g. "ScheduleManager" and include the trigger name as a parameter instead of having "simple" hardcoded. That class then could be used for changing the schedule of any trigger, by injecting the ScheduleManager (or preferably create an interface for ScheduleManager and inject that instead) to any controller that needs to use it:

```
@Service
public class SchedulerManagerImpl implements SchedulerManager {

    @Autowired
    private Scheduler scheduler;

    public void rescheduleSimpleTrigger(String triggerName, String cronExpression) throws ParseException,
            SchedulerException {

        CronTriggerImpl cronTrigger = (CronTriggerImpl) scheduler
                .getTrigger(new TriggerKey(triggerName));

        cronTrigger.setCronExpression(cronExpression);
        scheduler.rescheduleJob(cronTrigger.getKey(), cronTrigger);

    }
}
```

That way you can now just inject the SchedulerManager to any of your controllers that will be responsible for changing the schedule

```
@Autowired
private SchedulerManager schedulerManager;
```

Finally you may consider having the TriggerKey as a parameter of the rescheduleTrigger method instead of just the name, since this will allow you to also specify the group of the trigger in case you use one some day other than the default.